# BTC-Wallet from "Airgap.it" asks for Receipient-Adress-Prefix "1ABC". What format is that?

Tags: address-format, exodus

I am trying to set up a Cold and a Hot Wallet.

1. Hot Wallet = "Exodus" on my everyday mobile phone. Adressformat is Bech32 with Prefix "bc1" or legacy-prefix from format "P2PKH" then adresses start with "1".
2. Cold Wallet = "Airgap Vault" on offline Device plus "Airgap Wallet" on everyday mobile phone. Both from "airgap.it".
3. I tried to send a test amount from the Cold-Wallet to the Hot-Wallet, but Cold-Wallet "Airgap Wallet" only accepts BTC-Adresses starting with Prefix "1ABC". How do I obtain this adress from my "hot" Exodus-Wallet and how is this adress-standard/-format called?

I could only find BTC-Cash-related entries in Google, but BTC-Cash-Adresses start with "q" or "bitcoincash:q". Also the wallet software would have to be very misleading, because BTC-Cash is not even supposed to be supported. I can't even imagine that, so I guess I am really dumb right now. Any help is very much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: As I had Exodus and AirgapWallet on the same device I used copy&paste for the address instead of QR-Code. QR-Code of the same address is accepted by Cold-Companion-App "AirGap Wallet". Possibly some really weird validation-error. Up till now I wasn't able to transfer funds due to other problems, though. I keep this Question open in the mean time.

Answer (score 0):

The Prefix "1abc" is part prefix "1" and part wildcard "abc". so it asked for the P2PKH-format all along. there is NO secret third format with a fixed prefix that is always "1abc".

I reported the issue of the QR-code accepting BECH32-format with the developers. using the right address everything works like a charm and is a very nice alternative to a hardware-wallet if you have a old smartphone to spare.

Comment: I found fast and hands-on help in the Telegram-Group. If you have questions regarding airgap.it try https://t.me/AirGap